# Windows PC randomly shut down after a specific event occurs

Tags: windows, power-supply, shutdown

[image: whenever this event occurs,my pc will shut down]

[image: unexpected shutdown eventlog]

[Problem]
Every time UserModePowerService Event(atieclxx.exe related) occurs,
My PC will shutdown.
And this event occurs very randomly...

I wonder the process 'atieclxx.exe' have anything to do
with this problem.
I googled around it for a while, but not to much info about this problem.
someone asked the same question about it long time along,but no answer to it.
https://www.eightforums.com/threads/usermodepowerservice-causing-shutdown.30285/

[PC Spec Info]
CPU : Inter 12700K
GPU : AMD 6750xt
PSU : CoolerMaster 800W

PS:

1. I googled about this 'atieclxx.exe' and found that this is a AMD ATI External Events Client Module.
   so I turn off the service to see if it does any good to change my situation.
2. Besides I managed to change my Desktop PSU to see whether it helps.
3. Later when I'm ready, a reinstallation of OS is arranged.
   (Any other advice will be appreciated.)

Comment: after trying PS.1 , yet another error occurred and my PC keeps falling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I reinstall win10 instead of win11(PS.3),plus PS.2 applied ,My PC seems normal now.
If there comes any new infomation,I'll post it here.
Problem solved.

PS:
Maybe some power failures in my town affected my PC...(hope a UPS can help.)

2022-10-21

I contact the MSI user support,and changed my motherboard.
Things are getting back to normal now.
It's the motherboard!!!

2023-1-17

after about 3 months, same problem never appears.
It's hard to say what is the main cause of this problem.
but UPS really helps a lot.(I even begin to doubt about the electricity in my room)

--fin

Comment: Reinstallation does not help at all, and so does changing my PSU.   
After contacting MSI's user support team.   
I change my motherboard's mode from UEFI -> CSM.   
Hope it can help...